# Is a Virus detection plugin necessary?

Tags: plugins, virus

Nowdays a Virus detection plugin is necessary for Wordpress?

EDIT: I mean to prevent attacks and violations... for example i'm using this plugin: https://sucuri.net/wordpress-security/wordpress-security-monitoring and i recive daily emails about some "Login Failures" using "admin" as Username and some differents passwords from a lot of different IP address.

Comment: Anti virus?????

Comment: @PieterGoosen "Virus detection" just edited. I'm sleeping ahaha

Comment: Virus detection as in? Security plugins that gaurd against spamming and data mining, are you refering to that. Hacking can't be stopped via plugin, for this you need to make sure that your code, plugins and theme does not have obvious loop holes, that your server is up to date and so should your Wordpress version be

Comment: @PieterGoosen Well, for my clients i use to buy templates from different and certified markets...

Comment: That absolutely says nothing. I have seen many premium themes that is coded worstly than free themes on wordpress.org.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Question marks are no valid filler for comment length. Also an edit and a good answer can bust a myth here. Valid question.

Comment: @kaiser I did not say that it is an invalid question. I originally voted on it, yes, it was unclear what the question was. To be honest, as it stands, what virus protection? As for the question marks, why do we need to write 20 words when we can express something in two words. The comment filter sometimes doesn't make sense. Please post an answer if you wish to do that (*which became compulsary since you brought it up*)

Comment: @ialocin i just edited the first post with more informations.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, it isn't *necessary*. You can run WP site without security plugin just fine.

The benefits of security plugin are mostly in monitoring. The very plugin you link to has very extensive description of what it actually *does*. It is up to you if you see the value in that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are hosting, if you are on a shared host, most of them will run an antivirus scan on your site weekly, some do not, you will have to check. You can also do this your self by downloading your site onto  your pc and scanning it.

Short Answer, keep your wordpress upto date and run only quality plugins with HTTPS ([wordpress HTTPS tutorial](https://www.antivirustalk.com/we-run-wordpress-and-we-went-ssl-256-bit-https/)) and you should be ok. THis will change as you get more traffic.